# Actions on Google ReportState Json for C# .netcore 3.1

Tags: c#, actions-on-google, asp.net-core-3.1

We have the following json requirement for replying to Google HomeGraph.

```
{
  "requestId": "123ABC",
  "agentUserId": "user-123",
  "payload": {
    "devices": {
      "states": {
        "light-123": {
          "on": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I was able to fake this out with .netcore 2.1 and NewtonSoft. How do you represent this as an object for .netcore 3.1 and system.text.json? Specifically the variable string representing "light-123". From a controller I am using:

```
return new JsonResult(jsonObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use  a custom JSON property naming policy. It's a bit ugly.